# How to catch ids getting created and compare their attributes in rails active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Question model and a PossibleAnswer model the tables are as follows.

**possible_answers**

```
create_table "possible_answers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "question_id"
    t.string   "title"
end
```

**questions**

```
create_table "questions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "right_answer"
end
```

The association is (you could have guessed already but anyway)

Question.rb

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :possible_answers
end
```

PossibleAnswer.rb

```
class PossibleAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :question
end
```

Now I have a form where all the questions are posted with their respective choices. I have a controller to submit the answers by selecting the choices.

```
class RepliesController < ApplicationController
   def create
    @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:quiz_id])
    @reply = @quiz.replies.build reply_params
    if @reply.save
      redirect_to @quiz, notice: "Thank you for taking the quiz"
    end
  end
  def reply_params
    params.require(:reply).permit({ answers_attributes: [ :value, :question_id, :possible_answer_id ] })
  end
end
```

Now this create method is working fine. Once the user submits the quiz, the following data is created.

```
{"answers_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"possible_answer_id"=>"10", "question_id"=>"6"}}, "commit"=>"Finish quiz", "quiz_id"=>"1"}
```

Here the `possible_answer_id` is the option which user selected and the possible answer belongs to the `question_id`.

My question is, how can I compare the `title` from this possible_answer_id to the `right_answer` of the question_id.

I tried using find params and passing the id but didnt work.
Can anybody please help me here. I have a come a long way building this app and stuck here now.

Comment: Why not have `right_answer_id` in the question? This way you can compare ids directly.

Comment: Also, "didn't work" tells us nothing. __What__ didn't work (exact code)? Didn't work __how__?  Take a look at [ask] page and also this one: [mcve].

Comment: I would rather compare the values than ids.

Comment: I will update what I tried.

Comment: @user3576036 If you want to compare the values, this means you will have to make sure that the `right_answer` is always equal to a `possible_answer`'s title, using the same comparison logic (case-sensitive or not, striping spaces or not, etc). This seems pretty painful in comparison to a simple id matching test.

Comment: @MrYoshiji yes I know. I am myself adding both the right answers and choices from Ui. For now I ll make sure the strings are same. This is for time being.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about adding a `:correct, :boolean, default: :false` to your `possible_answers` table. That way when the user selects the answer you're able to find it and see if it's correct.

Having the answer string in both `question` and `possible_answers` isn't the most efficient solution.

Alternatively (If you want to keep the answer in the questions table) you could change `right_answer` to `possible_answer_id` and have a `has_one :possible_answer, as: :right_answer`. So you can do:

```
question.possible_answers   # returns list
question.right_answer       # returns just the single record of the correct answer
```

Comment: `right_answer` is a column under `questions` table.

Comment: Yeh, I would suggest removing this. In my solution right_answer would return the correct record from the `possible_answers` table

Comment: You want me to remove `right_answer` column from `questions` table and instead reference between `question` and `possible_answer` ?

Comment: @user3576036 this structure allows a `Question` to have several `right_answer`s (flexibility gained). Also, you can simply define in Question `has_many :right_answers, -> { where(correct: true) }` and compare the given `possible_answers`' id to the `right_answers`' id of that question _easily_